# Tiling images of different sizes in css

Tags: css, html

I have a few images I want to tile, like in the [image.](http://dev.xhaerithius.com/resources/stackoverflow_question.svg) There are 3 images of the same width & height, but one is larger, and should take up twice the space as the others.
The most I managed to get is to make it tile, but for the next row row to appear where the large image in the row above ends.
(If you don't get my explanation, it is shown in the image [here](http://dev.xhaerithius.com/resources/stackoverflow_question.svg).)
Here is the html:

```
        <div class="portfolio">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="" alt="" class="largeWidthImg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.portfolio {
position: absolute;
width: 77.1%;
top: 165%;;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);}

.smallWidthImg {
float: left;
width: 14.47%;
padding: 0 0.85% 0.85% 0.85%;}

.smallWidthImg {
float: left;
width: 14.47%;
padding: 0 0.85% 0.85% 0.85%;}

.smallWidthImg:first-child {
padding-left: 0;}

.smallWidthImg:last-child {
padding-right: 0;}

.largeWidthImg {
float: left;
width: 30.64%;
padding: 0 0.85% 0.85% 0.85%;}

.largeWidthImg:first-child {
padding-left: 0;}

.largeWidthImg:last-child {
padding-right: 0;}
```

Is this possible with only CSS?
(I do not know javascript, so I cannot do it using javascript)
Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

How about working with colums?

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="./nodejs.png" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="./nodejs.png" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="./nodejs.png" alt="" class="smallWidthImg"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="./nodejs.png" alt=""class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="./nodejs.png" alt=""class="smallWidthImg"/>
                <img src="./nodejs.png" alt=""class="smallWidthImg"/>
            </div>
            <img src="./nodejs.png" alt="" class="largeWidthImg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What would the css be for the div.col ?